# Why did this character teach the Hogwarts students more than he should have?

Tags: harry-potter

During GoF in the Harry Potter series, Profesor Moody

> (who is actually Barty Crouch Jr. using Polyjuice Potion)

teaches the kids in his class about unforgivable curses, but then goes into it in detail about them and how they are pronounced, how they work and even how to resist some, like the Imperius curse. He even went as far as saying

> "Earn you a one-way ticket to Azkaban. Correct. The Ministry says you are too young to see what these curses do. I say different! You need to know what you're up against. You need to be prepared..."

He also has them practice resisting the imperius curse

> "The Imperius curse can be fought, and I’ll be teaching you how, but it takes real strength of character, and not everyone’s got it. Better avoid being hit with it…"

It would seem that teaching students spells to protect themselves from the ambush that you're a major contributor in is not the best plan. That's like arming an enemy country with a missile defense system just before your about to attack them with a missile. And i know that some might say that that he didn't think that Harry would be able to defeat the dark lord anyway but still, why not just teach the 4th year Defense Against the Dark Arts textbook information and be over with it?

Comment: I suggest you fix either your title or your body.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9299/how-reliable-is-anything-mad-eye-moody-taught-in-defense-against-dark-arts

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168569/why-did-moody-suggest-to-harry-that-he-should-consider-becoming-an-auror

Comment: Maybe I'm confused but wasn't Moody locked in a crate for most of the book? It would have been Barty Crouch Jr teaching the children. Barty was working for Voldemort and would have taught evil curses as a way to discredit the school.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off your quote is bad

> “So — straight into it. Curses. They come in many strengths and forms.
>   Now, according to the Ministry of Magic, I’m supposed to teach you
>   countercurses and leave it at that. I’m not supposed to show you what
>   illegal Dark curses look like until you’re in the sixth year. You’re
>   not supposed to be old enough to deal with it till then. But Professor
>   Dumbledore’s got a higher opinion of your nerves, he reckons you can
>   cope, and I say, the sooner you know what you’re up against, the
>   better. How are you supposed to defend yourself against something
>   you’ve never seen? - *Goblet of Fire*

The ministry fully intends students to see these curses, according to this quote, the 4th year students are simply learning about them BEFORE they usually would. So he would already be showing them to his 6th year students anyway following as the basic textbook curriculum.

Second, bringing in ex-auror Mad Eye Moody, implies Dumbledore expected more, practical education. Moody is a battle hardened, front line fighter, of the dark arts, and as a habitual line crosser like Dumbledore, you would expect him to do things the "ministry" does not approve of. Teaching safely out of the book is something Moody would never have done.

Third, Voldemort himself has great respect for the education Hogwarts provides. While disliking subjects such as Muggle Studies, Voldemort wants magical pureblood children to receive a good education, and limiting that is anathema to Voldemort.

Finally Crouch uses this, on day 1, to set into motion a plan to help Harry with the second task of the tri-wizard tournament. Nevelle distraught seeing the curse that made his parents go insane is set up to help Harry.

> Didn’t you realize that the
>   book you needed was in your dormitory all along? I planted it there
>   early on, I gave it to the Longbottom boy, don’t you remember?
>   Magical Water Plants of the Mediterranean.